# Add a user to Ubuntu server from PHP script

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, sudo

I am trying to write a PHP script which executes a shell command (via `system()`?) to add a new user to the server. I am thinking about using `useradd` or `adduser` but don't know how I will get it to work. What flags are necessary to execute `useradd` in a script? And how would I set the permissions on the script so it executes properly? This doesn't work:

```
<?

$user = $_GET['user'];

system("sudo useradd -m -p 4dk/kBWvKaP52/POJYOZGLam8qZnCkQtdw== $user; echo $user");

?>
```

Comment: Does the user running the script have sudo permission?

Comment: You will add a user `$user`? What should the `echo` do?

Comment: @wallyk It's a web page, so I am assuming the user running it is Apache...?

Comment: @KingCrunch Yes, `$user` is a GET variable. Echo is just for testing purposes.

Comment: A, I see: double quotes.

Comment: @stooploopl:  so is user `apache` permitted to `sudo` the `useradd` command?

Comment: Thats a huge security issue! I would recommend, that you think about it. Or tell me, which server this should run on :D

Comment: @wallyk Actually the user is www-data I think.

Comment: @KingCrunch I know it's a big security issue, but I am going to secure it - this is just a test version to get the basic functionality added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to add a line to `/etc/sudoers` like

```
www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/useradd
```

This allows www-data to run the useradd command.

You may also need to comment out this line, if it exists in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults requiretty
```

By the way, it's a good idea to escape your inputs with [escapeshellarg()](https://www.php.net/escapeshellarg):

```
$user = escapeshellarg($_GET['user']);
system("sudo useradd -m -p 4dk/kBWvKaP52/POJYOZGLam8qZnCkQtdw== $user; echo $user");
```

Comment: @stooploopl:  check the server log and system log, and maybe the security log (if security is enabled).  Somewhere there is a message hinting at the cause of the problem.